# Where should AutoLayout code be placed?

Tags: ios, autolayout, nslayoutconstraint

When I'm doing the initial setup of a `UIView`'s subviews, if I initialise a `UIView`:

```
//Listing A
UIView *redBox = [[UIView alloc] init];
[redBox setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];
[self.view addSubview:redBox];
[redBox setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];
```

And I want to programmatically apply Auto Layout constraints to it:

```
//Listing B
NSArray *constraints = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-[redBox(100)]" options:0 metrics:nil views:@{@"redBox": redBox}];
[self.view addConstraints:constraints];
constraints = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|-[redBox(100)]" options:0 metrics:nil views:@{@"redBox": redBox}];
[self.view addConstraints:constraints];
```

Where should Listing B go?

Should it always immediately follow Listing A?

Or, if we're in a `UIView` subclass, should it go into:

- `updateConstraints`
- `initWithFrame` or
- `layoutSubviews` ?

Similarly, if we're in a `UIViewController` subclass, and I place Listing A in `viewDidLoad`, should Listing B immediately follow it or should it go into:

- `initWithNibName:bundle:`
- `viewWillLayoutSubviews` or
- `updateViewConstraints` ?

Answer (score 1):

I often put it all in a method (or series of methods) called `setUpConstraints` or something like this.

Then I call that method from `viewDidLoad`.

If you're doing it in a `UIView` then I call my `setupConstraints` method from the `init` methods and `awakeFromNib`.

Having said that the method `updateViewConstraints` is already provided for you for this purpose so you could call your `setupConstraints` method from there.

Comment: Where in the docs does it say that constraints should be setup in `awakeFromNib` or in `initWithFrame`? I'm confused because [the docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/uiview_class/uiview/uiview.html) say "implement [updateConstraints] if your view needs to create custom constraints between your subviews."

Comment: It doesn't. Where in the documentation does it say where you should create an array for your data model? It doesn't. There are a million different ways to solve the same problem in programming. I'm just providing a few. I didn't need to and now I wish I hadn't.

Comment: My question is not "how do you guys use Auto Layout". Apple provides a [View Programming Guide](http://bit.ly/1aEbOez), a [View Controller Programming Guide](http://bit.ly/1eMPoKo), and WWDC videos on the matter. So although there are a million different ways to solve a problem in programming, some are right and others are wrong. Which is why I asked you to justify your answer. Which is why you shouldn't post an answer if you can't or don't want to justify it.

Answer (score -1):

`viewDidLoad` is the best place to apply the custom layout because it will not conflict with xib constraint at initialisation!

Comment: Wrong. If the constraints you defined in the xib contradict those you defined in `viewDidLoad` you'll get an `Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints` error.

Comment: Again, are you asking a question or are you testing the knowledge of others? You seem to know better than the people attempting to help you.

Comment: Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints error?? I really don't know this term, if you know then please explain better then pointing someone answer negative!